# Set [Embed] attribute value dynamically

Tags: actionscript

I am new to Action script. 
Is there any possibility to set the source attribute value dynamically at run time?
for e.g
in the code 
Embed(source="assets/images/image.pdf",mimeType="application/octet-stream");

I need to set 
source="set pdf file name using a variable or reading from config xml"

Please provide some example snippets or links for reference
Thanks in advance.

Thanks
SRR

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Conditional Compilation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html) will get you some way to achieving what you want.